# How to loop a php code?

Tags: php, loops, dry

I wanted to do the `DRY` approach in my code but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. And also, I want to hide the entire code if there's no `image_1`. Hope you could help me do the trick.

Here's the code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php
    $image = get_field('image_1');
    if(get_field('image_1'))
    {
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('image_link_1') . '">';?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php echo '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/image.png">';
    } ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php
    $image = get_field('image_2');
    if(get_field('image_2'))
    {
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('image_link_2') . '">';?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php echo '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/image.png">';
    } ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php
    $image = get_field('image_3');
    if(get_field('image_3'))
    {
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('image_link_3') . '">';?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php echo '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/image.png">';
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @JannisMattheis I want to loop the code.

Comment: As Jannis is saying, it's great that you already spent some time trying to figure it out! If you show us how far you've come, we can answer your question what you should do differently!

Comment: @stuXnet I can't make the loop work.

Comment: You did **not** implement a loop, yet... :-(

Comment: @RubyAnnRosales right now, I don't see a loop in your question, so it's hard to guess what's wrong with it :/ Could you update your question with your (not working) loop?

Comment: @MarcoS yeah. couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @stuXnet there's nothing wrong with the code. it's just that i want to loop it but don't know how.

Comment: @RubyAnnRosales ah, I understand! Have you looked at the official documentation? Example 1 should be quite easy to adapt. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @stuXnet thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 2):

You should put differences to arrays and then wrap everything into `for` loop:

```
<?php
  $images = array('image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3');
  $links = array('image_link_1', 'image_link_2', 'image_link_3');

  for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <?php
    $image = get_field($images[$i]);
    if(get_field($images[$i])){
      echo '<a href="' . get_field($links[$i]) . '">';
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
  <?php echo '</a>';
    } else {
      echo '<img src="http://localhost/image.png">';
    }
  ?>
</div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Btw, how can I hide it if no `image_1` is uploaded?

Comment: @RubyAnnRosales i can think of multiple solutions but the easiest one is probably to change `for` condition to: `for($i=0; $images[0] && $i<3; $i++)`

Comment: it's not working. the images echoed in `else` are still showing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint...:

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'>" . "\n";
    $image = get_field("image_" . ($i + 1));
    ...
    echo "</div>" . "\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should get you started if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
<?php for ($q = 1; $q <= 3; $q++) {
    $image_loop = 'image_' . $q;

    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';

    if ($image = get_field($image_loop)) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('image_link_' . $q) . '">';
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php echo '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/image.png">';
    } ?>
</div>

<?php } // end loop ?>
```

Comment: But, how can I hide it if no `image_1` is uploaded?

Comment: That's left as an exercise for you. Stackoverflow isn't a place to get your code written for you! Hint: maybe test for `image_1` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions here will work as well but here's what I would do:

First arrange the images in an associative array with keys being the image name and values being the image link and then iterate via a foreach loop.

I generally try to not echo HTML unless strictly necessary.

```
<?php
$array = [
    "image_1" => "image_link_1",
    "image_2" => "image_link_2",
    "image_3" => "image_link_3",
    "image_4" => "image_link_4"
];

foreach ($array as $name => $link):
    $image = get_field($name); 
    if ($image): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?=get_field($link)?>">
            <img src="<?= $image['url']; ?>" title="<?= $image['title']; ?>" alt="<?= $image['alt']; ?>" />        
        </a> 
        <?php else: ?>
            <img src="http://localhost/image.png">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```